# Is this pattern matching expression equivalent to not null

Tags: c#, syntax

I stumbled upon [this code](https://github.com/devmentors/Nanoservice/blob/37f5e3afee84dabefad654495ea0839e90032200/src/Sidecar/Program.cs#L71) on github:

```
if (requestHeaders is {})
```

and I don't understand what it does exactly.

Upon experimenting it's seems to only be false when requestHeaders is null.

Is this just another way of writing `if (requestHeaders != null)` or `if (!(requestHeaders is null))`?

Comment: It checks that `requestHeaders` is anonymous object and has any value except null, actually you are right with `null` checks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The pattern-matching in C# supports property pattern matching. 
e.g.

```
if (requestHeaders  is HttpRequestHeader {X is 3, Y is var y})
```

The semantics of a property pattern is that it first tests if the input is non-null. so it allows you to write:

```
if (requestHeaders is {}) // will check if object is not null
```

You can write the same type checking in any of the following manner that will provide a `Not Null` Check included:

```
if (s is object o) ... // o is of type object
if (s is string x) ... // x is of type string
if (s is {} x) ... // x is of type string
if (s is {}) ...
```

[Read more here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/patterns.md).

Comment: Is there any reason to use this pattern rather than if (!= null) ?

Comment: In this case, I don't think it's any different. It's same as using !=null.

Comment: I think the pattern must be `HttpRequestHeader  {X: 3, Y: var y}` where `X` and `Y` are properties of `HttpRequestHeader`. I recently used `p is IImage { Image: { } img } imageItem` which is equivalent to `p is IImage imageItem && imageItem.Image != null` and the image is assigned to `img` at the same time. You could also simply write `p is IImage { Image: { } img }` if you only need `img` and don't need `imageItem`.

Comment: how do you know this information? this is not present in any official documentation. the only place this info appears is here on stack overflow.

Answer (score 5):

As an addition to @vendettamit's answer:

Since C# 9, it is the same as writing

`if (requestHeaders is not null)`

which does not require any further explanation