# Use pattern matching to test a property to be not null and another being a list starting with given elements

Tags: c#, .net, pattern-matching

My task is to use Pattern Matching to make an `Employee` selection where the `Email` will not be `null` and the first two languages of the employee will be `"ru"` and `"en"`
How do I make a check for not null and check the first two elements of the Languages ?

Here's what I have

```
public static string IsRuEnWithEmail(Employee emp) => emp switch
{
    { Email:  != null, Languages: { "ru", "en" } } =>
        $"{emp.FCs}, {emp.Email}, {emp.Role}",
    _ => "",
};
```

It doesn't work at all
Errors say that it is impossible to compare this way

Comment: Why make it complicated in an expression? What's the win here? Any new programmer has to look 5x to understand it. If you can write software everybody understands, you on the right track. Try to write it in a non-expression way.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen This is the first part of the assignment from the university, then there are more complex ones

Comment: "This is the first part of the assignment" the first part is to make it as an exprression?

Comment: Does it just say "use pattern matching" or specifically pattern matching in conjunction with a awitch statement as expression-bodied method? Can you post the exact wording of the assignment? Because `{ if (emp is not null) ... ` would technically also be "pattern matching".

Comment: BTW: I don't know if it's just me, but a `string` return type from a method with name `IsXXX()` would be rather surprising for me. And I'd have to refer to docs to see what it does.

Comment: Also: _"My task is to use Pattern Matching **to make an Employee selection**"_ That sounds (to me) more like `IEnumerable<Employee>.Select( x => x is not null && ... )` ?

Comment: @Fildor i'm with you and he is calling it "checking".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pattern matching is relatively new in C#, even more for [list patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#list-patterns) which begin with C# 11 which was released this month.

A not [null matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59361400) is created with `{ }`.
A partial list matching is created with `[item1, item2, ..]`

All together:

```csharp
// We expect a method prefixed with "Is" to return a boolean
// but OP provided this signature
public static string IsRuEnWithEmail(Employee emp) => emp switch
{
    { Email: {}, Languages: ["ru", "en", ..] } => $"{emp.FCs}, {emp.Email}, {emp.Role}",
    _ => "",
};
```

Working demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IRhIHx).